# Display a stream images in Google Colab using OpenCV

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, google-colaboratory

I have a stream of images and have to display it in Google Colab notebook such that it looks like a video,  But what I get is a image under image ...

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

# importing cv2
import cv2
import imutils
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
from IPython.display import clear_output
import os

folder = r'/content/drive/images/'

for filename in os.listdir(folder) :
    VALID_FORMAT = (".jpg", ".JPG", ".jpeg", ".JPEG", ".png", ".PNG")
    if filename.upper().endswith(VALID_FORMAT):
        path = folder + filename
        image = cv2.imread(path)
        # resize image
        frame = imutils.resize(image, width=1200)
        # show the image
        cv2_imshow(frame) 
        cv2.waitKey(20)
```

Comment: Move cv2_imshow and cv2.waitKey() outside of if/else condition block.

Comment: It gives the same results as before

Comment: I don't know if it has method for this. It may need to use JavaScript code to replace image directly on canvas. Somewhere in Google Colab advanced examples you can find JavaScript example which use JavaScript to get image from webcam and display it.

Comment: But not all pictures will images

Comment: maybe you should `clear_output` after very image (and after waitkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if some function can display image in the same place.

But I have code which I used with cv2 to display frames from webcam as video.

Here reduced version.

`imshow(name, image)` creates `<img id="name">` and replaces `src/url` with image converted to string `base64` and browser shows it as image.

`imshow()` uses `name` to check if already exist `<img id="name">` and it replaces previous image.

```
from IPython.display import display, Javascript
from google.colab.output import eval_js
from base64 import b64encode
import cv2

def imshow(name, img):
  """Put frame as <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,...."> """

  js = Javascript('''
  async function showImage(name, image, width, height) {
    img = document.getElementById(name);
    if(img == null) {
      img = document.createElement('img');
      img.id = name;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
    img.src = image;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
  }
  ''')

  height, width = img.shape[:2]

  ret, data = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)   # compress array of pixels to JPG data
  data = b64encode(data)                  # encode base64
  data = data.decode()                    # convert bytes to string
  data = 'data:image/jpg;base64,' + data  # join header ("data:image/jpg;base64,") and base64 data (JPG)

  display(js)
  eval_js(f'showImage("{name}", "{data}", {width}, {height})')  # run JavaScript code to put image (JPG as string base64) in <img>
                                          # `name` and `data` in needs `" "` to send it as text, not as name of variabe.
```

And here code which uses it to display image [Lenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenna) from Wikipedia.

```
import requests
import cv2
import numpy as np
import time

url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/7d/Lenna_%28test_image%29.png'

data = requests.get(url)

frame1 = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer( data.content, np.uint8), 1)
frame2 = cv2.cvtColor(frame1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

for _ in range(3):
  imshow("temp", frame1)
  time.sleep(1)
  imshow("temp", frame2)
  time.sleep(1)
```

---

**EDIT**

Display images in two "windows" using `imshow("img1", ...)` and `imshow("img2", ...)`

```
import os
import cv2
import imutils
import time

folder = r'/content/drive/images/'

VALID_FORMAT = (".JPG", ".JPEG", ".PNG")

for number, filename in enumerate(os.listdir(folder)):
    if filename.upper().endswith(VALID_FORMAT):
        path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        image = cv2.imread(path)
        
        frame = imutils.resize(image, width=400)

        number = number % 2        
        imshow(f"img{number}", frame)

        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: this is working, but fps too slow even though reducing time sleep.

Comment: @CitraDewi problem can be also Google Lab. It has to send every image from server to browser and use `JavaScript` to display it - and all this needs time. And on local computer it may run faster. On local computer you could also first read all images, resize them and later display them.